# C# Azure Authenticathion an Identity

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity

**Environement**

I developed Webapp with C# .NETCore 2.0, webapp works with Azure AD Authenticathion and work perfectly. Webapp should allow external user to use webapp, for this goal created in Azure AD as Guest, and works perfectly.

**Problem**
My customer wants external users to use webapp without Azure AD authenticathion, because external users didn't waste time registering Azure AD.

**Recomendations** 
Well, to goal this i thinking use ASP.NET Identity, however my question is how i can have one webapp with 2 different authentication types (ASP.Net Identity and Azure AD), what is the best scenario ?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure multiple identity providers within your ASP.NET web app so it would be possible to add ASP.NET Identity.

However, it realy depends on your requirements.  You may consider using [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) which enables your customer to use social accounts or theire emails and also has a directory behind it.